# how to deal with jest mock function of a module and typescript type

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I use `ts-jest` and `jest` to write my testing files with typescript.

I am confused how to typing the mock function of a module.

Here is my code:

`./module.ts`:

```
import {IObj} from '../interfaces';

const obj: IObj = {
  getMessage() {
    return `Her name is ${this.genName()}, age is ${this.getAge()}`;
  },

  genName() {
    return 'novaline';
  },

  getAge() {
    return 26;
  }
};

export default obj;
```

`./module.test.ts`:

```
import * as m from './module';

describe('mock function test suites', () => {

  it('t-1', () => {
    // I think the jest.Mock<string> type here is not correct.
    m.genName: jest.Mock<string> = jest.fn(() => 'emilie'); 
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(m.genName)).toBeTruthy();
    expect(m.genName()).toBe('emilie');
    expect(m.getMessage()).toEqual('Her name is emilie, age is 26');
    expect(m.genName).toHaveBeenCalled(); 

  });

});
```

how to type the mock function `genName` of module `m`?

`typescript` give me an error here:

> Error:(8, 7) TS2540:Cannot assign to 'genName' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

Answer (score 19):

This is how I have solved the same problem and how I do all of my mocking and spying now.

```
import * as m from './module';

describe('your test', () => {
  let mockGenName;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockGenName = jest.spyOn(m, 
      'genName').mockImplemetation(() => 'franc');
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    mockGenName.mockRestore();
  })


  test('your test description', () => {
    // do something that calls the genName function
    expect(mockGenName).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })

})
```

With this setup, you can programmatically change the implementation of the mock for different tests, and then assert that the function was called and what it was called with, all while clearing your mock in between tests and after all tests.

Comment: I get TypeError: jest.spyOn(...).mockImplemetation is not a function

Comment: @ykonda I fixed the misspelling

Comment: I get "TypeError: Cannot redefine property: genName"

Comment: Not work for me. Got error when mock `get` from  `dot-prop`:  `Cannot redefine property: get`

Answer (score 4):

Try this one - https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#typescript

In short there are only three strategies possible

1. Mock the entire module being imported and get handler to the mocked function to manipulate it (jest.Mock(), jest.MockedFunction)
2. Mock the module partially being imported and get handler to the mocked function to manipulate it (jest.Mock() with factory, jest.MockedFunction)
3. Import the module as is and then spy on the function which needs to be mocked (jest.spy())

Answer (score 3):

You want to mock the module and then alter the exported function within it. This should *replace* your import statement.

```
jest.mock('./module', () => ({
    genName: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'emilie')
}))
```

Comment: This doesn't work as genName is scoped locally to that block and is not available throughout the file

Comment: I'm using this throughout my code, so it does indeed work. If you need to test that genName is called (or something like that), you can assign the jest.fn() to a mock* variable outside of the block and reference that:

`genName: mockGenName`

then `expect(mockGenName).toHaveBeenCalled()` or whatever.

Comment: Solution suggested by @trevorgk works fine. I only wanted to highlight that you may want to change implementation in particular test: ```it('returns franc', () => { m.genName.mockImplementationOnce(() => 'franc') })```

Comment: @phillyslick Thanks for the solution, but in this case, how do you test the function itself? Like: ```expect(genName()).toReturnSomething...```?

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as m from './module'

jest.mock('./module', () => ({
    genName: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'emilie')
    // will return "enilie" for all tests
}))

it('returns franc', () => {
  m.genName.mockImplementationOnce(() => 'franc')
  // will return "franc" for this particular test
})
```

Comment: The second mockImple does not work I get Property 'mockImplementation' does not exist on type '() => Promise<any>'.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I got the error is:

> The properties of a module object foo (import * as foo from 'foo') are like the properties of a frozen object.

For more info, see [In ES6, imports are live read-only views on exported values](https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_in-es6-imports-are-live-read-only-views-on-exported-values)

When I changed `import * as m from './module'` to `import m from './module';`, The error is gone.

Package versions:

```json
"typescript": "^3.6.4"
"ts-jest": "^24.1.0"
"jest": "^24.9.0",
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  //...
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm mocking it a follow :

```
jest.mock('./module')
const {genName} = require('./module')
```

and in my test :

```
 genName.mockImplementationOnce(() => 'franc')
```

works great for me and no typescript errors

Comment: Would be great if can provide explaination of your answer